# Laravel 5 is loading old css

Tags: html, css, laravel, gulp

I am editing my css located in resources\assets\sass\app.css then I run gulp watch but it seems that laravel is ignoring the changes I made in my css.

I tried editing the css directly in public\css\app.css but still when I view my page in the browser the style is not working.

For example, my page's background color is white but I changed it to red, the background of my page in the browser is still white.

When I tried the view source in the browser and clicked on the filename in the 
, the background-color: #fff;

Hope you get my point. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache and reloading the page? http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/

Comment: Clear your browser's cache and reload page.

Answer (score 9):

You should clear all cache. First, clear view cache:

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Then clear browser cache and reload the page.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the "[cache busting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting)" feature via versioning in Laravel mix so that each new .css file saved is provisioned with a unique id.  This way, every change made will force the browser to fetch the latest version of the css file.  You won't even need to then hard refresh!

Really easy to implement. Just add `version()` to your mix:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .version();
```

And then refer to your .js or .css asset using `mix()` instead of `asset()`.

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

If you see cache issues with your css locally, it's only going to be worse for your site users down the line who could end up seeing all sorts of issues with out of date/sync css files.

This is the solution to this problem and everyone should use it on production env.

Comment: This is the clearest, simplest description of this feature that I've seen anywhere. Implementing this change on an existing Laravel project took a matter of minutes. This is extremely useful for our test environments as well so that our QA and business approval users don't come back to us with phantom problems that are the result of outdated js and css files.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a *hard refresh*. 
**Ctrl + F5** on Windows I guess, on Mac it's **Cmd+Shift+R**.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + R also applicable on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use composer to refresh auto-loaded files and clear the cache. From your project root directory, run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and

```
composer clear-cache
```

this should remove your old css files

Comment: if you are having problems with old compiled php files, you could also run: `php artisan clear-compiled`